# Understanding UTF8Encode and UTF8ToString in Rad Studio

Tags: delphi, c++builder

For legacy reasons, I need to use a old source that uses AnsiString instead of UnicodeString in Rad Studio.

So, my plan is to use String most of time, and just when I need to use this library, convert to AnsiString, and the same, from AnsiString to String as soon as possible.

```
String temp = L"汉语/漢語";
AnsiString raw=UTF8Encode(temp);
String dest = UTF8ToString(raw);
```

When I check , I get ??? instead of 汉语/漢語. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What you are doing wrong is using `AnsiString`. You need to stop doing that. You need to hold your data in a Unicode encoding. ANSI won't get the job done. Either UTF-16 or UTF-8, but not ANSI. Without any knowledge of the legacy motivations it's hard to point you at a solution.

Comment: I know it, but the problem is that the old library uses AnsiString to store binary data, in this case UTF8. I would need to rewrite the entire library, so I am trying to use it without critical changes. I thought I could continue using AnsiString to store binary data, without any page conversion. Is it not possible?

Comment: I don't know enough about the C++Builder emulation of Delphi's strings, but in Delphi, I would use `UTF8String` for UTF-8 encoded text, and `TBytes` for binary data. I would take the time to refactor that. Note that (at least in Delphi), you can directly convert between `UTF8String` and `UnicodeString` without any loss.

Comment: I am using UTF8Encode because it returns RawByteString, and I thought that AnsiString does not convert the data from RawByteString, but obviously I am wrong. In any case, I need to use AnsiString to store binary data if I do not want to re-write the library. I know it is not the best way, but for now, it is the option I would like.

Comment: Using `AnsiString` to store binary data is terribly wrong kludge from very old times before introduction of dynamic arrays (`of Byte`).

Comment: I know, but the library is a complex crypto library (3DES, ...) that uses AnsiString to store binary data. To re-write it is not viable.

Comment: In C++, there are enough STL types to store binary data, so I really wonder why anyone ever used The C++Builder emulaton of AnsiString to store such data. Now UTF-8 encoded text is different. There, AnsiString won't cut it either, but UTF8String does. I'm afraid you'll have to refactor the code to use a byte vector to store binary and something like UTF8String to store UTF-8 encoded text, because AnsiString encodes too, to a codepage, and that is not what you want.

Comment: Because the library is written in Delphi, not in C++

Comment: Crypto libraries generally work on bytes, so use a byte vector for everything. Using it as is is not viable either.

Comment: Ah, the library is written in Delphi? Ok, that makes things a little more complicated for you. In Delphi versions (and probably C++Builder versions) after 2009 you will get in trouble when you use AnsiString.

Comment: If you cannot re-write the code then I guess you will need to give up. Either that or revert to a pre-Unicode version of Delphi. On the other hand 3DES is pretty routine. There are many decent libraries that can perform this crypto. Libraries that don't confuse binary and text data. Perhaps it's time to move beyond this badly designed library.

Comment: The code you have presented works correctly, at least in Delphi. There is no problem if you convert Unicode to UTF-8 AnsiString (UTF8Encode) and then convert back (UTF8ToString). The problem is in your code which you did not provide.

Comment: There is not more code. The example I have provided is enough to replicate the problem. I have created a Test Unit with the above code, and if I check 'raw' variable with raw[1],  raw[2], ... I can see that AnsiString has converted all Chinese chars to ?, losing the initial information. The problem is in AnsiString raw=UTF8Encode(temp).

Comment: Also, I think AnsiString is not the same than UTF8Encode. UTF8Encode uses the 65001 codepage and AnsiString uses the 0 page (defined in Windows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to stay away from using `AnsiString` as a binary buffer in Delphi/C++Builder 2009 and later.  It is a codepaged string, and that can cause subtle/unexpected data conversions from one codepage to another as the string gets passed around.  In your case, the `???` is a direct result of data actually being converted to an Ansi codepage that does not support the Unicode characters you are trying to use.

You really should be using `TBytes` for binary data.  For a UTF-8 encoded string, use `UTF8String` instead:

```cpp
String temp = L"汉语/漢語";
UTF8String raw = UTF8String(temp);
...
String dest = String(raw);
```

With that said, since you have to interop with a 3rd party library that expects a UTF-8 encoded `AnsiString` as a binary buffer<sup>1</sup>, then you can at least use a `UTF8String` variable and type-cast it (not assign it) to `AnsiString` when passing it to the library:

```cpp
library_function(*(reinterpret_cast<AnsiString*>(&raw));
```

Or:

```cpp
library_function(reinterpret_cast<AnsiString&>(raw));
```

This works because `AnsiString`, `UTF8String`, and `RawByteString` are all based on the same `AnsiStringT` base type:

```cpp
typedef AnsiStringT<0> AnsiString;
typedef AnsiStringT<65001> UTF8String;
typedef AnsiStringT<65535> RawByteString;
```

And thus all share a common memory layout and implementation under the hood, and Delphi will accept this just fine.

If you want to be really adventurous, you should update the library to use `RawByteString` or `UTF8String` (if not `TBytes`) instead of `AnsiString`, then you don't need a type-cast at all<sup>2</sup>:

```cpp
library_function(raw);
```

<sup>1</sup>: you really need to get a new version of that library, or use a different library.

<sup>2</sup>: this is the kind of situation that `RawByteString` was originally intended for. It was never intended to be used for standalone variables, but for function parameters that can accept any type of 8-bit string as input without performing a data conversion.

Answer (score 1):

For now, I have found a solution:

```cpp
AnsiString UTF8ToBin(UTF8String value)
{
   AnsiString dest;
   dest.SetLength(value.Length());
   memcpy(dest.c_str(), value.c_str(), value.Length());
   return dest;
}
```

It allows me to use the library using AnsiString type to store binary data, in this case, UTF8.

I am very clear that I would need to use TBytes for binary data, but I could not rewrite the library.

Comment: Why not just use `RawByteString` as-is instead of `AnsiString`? Assigning a `UTF8String` to a `RawByteString` preserves the data. Assigning a `UTF8String` to an `AnsiString` does not. `RawByteString raw=UTF8Encode(temp);` or even `RawByteString raw=UTF8String(temp);` since `UTF8Encode()` is deprecated. If the library only accepts `AnsiString` specifically and not `RawByteString` generically, you could always use a typecast: `UTF8String raw=temp; library(*(AnsiString*)&raw);` since `(Ansi|Utf8|Raw)String` share a common memory layout and implementation as they are all based on `AnsiStringT`.

Comment: Great, `library(*(AnsiString*)&raw)` is a another solution. Thank you.